# camera preview is stretching in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I working on camera app, so I have implemented the camera preview in fragment, so the result it stretched the preview, In layout I am using surface view it works fine on front camera, but it stretched the preview in back camera this is my code.

```
public class Camera_fragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, FragmentInterface {
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean previewing = false;
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    int CameraId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);
        //getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        display = ((WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("turnstrr", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        getActivity().getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        Imgvw1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
        imgvw2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView17);
        imgvw3 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView19);
        imgvw4 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView20);
        Img_switch_camera = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Switch_camera);
        img_cross1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
        imgcross2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView23);
        img_cross3 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView24);
        imgcross4 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView25);
        Img_camera_click = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera_click);
        Btn_next = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Next);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pb_loading);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        tb = new TinyDB(getActivity());
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        // recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        // initRecorder();

        Img_switch_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                } catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                camera.release();
                if (CameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                    CameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
                } else {
                    camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
                    CameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
                }
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                Camera.Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
                // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
                //  Camera.Size optimalSize = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
                // previewSize.width = 720;
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);


                // start preview with new settings
                camera.setParameters(parameters);

                // Set the holder size based on the aspect ratio
//                int size = Math.min(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
//                double ratio = (double) previewSize.width / previewSize.height;
//
//                surfaceHolder.setFixedSize((int) (size * ratio), size);
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

                camera.startPreview();
            }
        });

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        //camera = Camera.open();

        try {
            camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Camera.Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
//                Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
//                optimalSize.width=  1280;
//                optimalSize.height= 720;
            parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
            // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
//                Camera.Size previewSize = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
//                // previewSize.width = 720;
//                parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);


            // start preview with new settings
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            CameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        } catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fail to connect to camera service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
                android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);
                int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                int degrees = 0;
                switch (rotation) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                        degrees = 0;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                        degrees = 90;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        degrees = 180;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        degrees = 270;
                        break;
                }

                int result;
                //int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
                if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                    result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
                } else { // back-facing
                    result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                }


                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                Camera.Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
//                Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
//                optimalSize.width=  1280;
//                optimalSize.height= 720;
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
                // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
//                Camera.Size previewSize = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
//                // previewSize.width = 720;
//                parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);


                // start preview with new settings
                camera.setParameters(parameters);

                // Set the holder size based on the aspect ratio
//                int size = Math.min(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
//                double ratio = (double) optimalSize.width / optimalSize.height;
//
//                surfaceHolder.setFixedSize((int) (size * ratio), size);
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // camera.stopPreview();
//        if (camera != null) {
//            camera.release();
//            camera = null;
//        }
    }



    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;

        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Find size
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();


            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                try {
                    fos.write(data);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                fos.close();
                camera.startPreview();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            //     String s = null;
//            try {
//                FileReader fd = new FileReader();
//
//                 s = fd.getFileAsString(pictureFile);
//                Array_items.add(s);
//            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }

            String path = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();

//            if (Array_items.size() == 1) {
//                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
//                options.inSampleSize = 5;
//                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
//                Imgvw1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//                return;
//                // Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(Imgvw1);
//            } else if (Array_items.size() == 2) {
//                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
//                options.inSampleSize = 5;
//                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
//                imgvw2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//                //  Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(imgvw2);
//            } else if (Array_items.size() == 3) {
//                try {
//                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//                    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
//                    options.inSampleSize = 5;
//                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
//                    imgvw3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
//
//                // Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(imgvw3);
//            } else if (Array_items.size() == 4) {
//                try {
//                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//                    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
//                    options.inSampleSize = 5;
//                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
//                    imgvw4.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
//                // Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(imgvw4);
//            }
            //  ImageView img_cross1, imgcross2, img_cross3, imgcross4;
            if (Array_items.size() < 4) {
                Array_items.add(path);
                Img_camera_click.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera_blue_normal);
                tb.putListString("list", Array_items);
                if (Strfor_img1.contentEquals("niomage1")) {
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    options.inSampleSize = 5;
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
                        ExifInterface exif = null;
                        try {
                            exif = new ExifInterface(path);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                        Bitmap bmRotated = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
                        Imgvw1.setImageBitmap(bmRotated);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Strfor_img1 = "setimage1";
                    img_cross1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return;
                    // Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(Imgvw1);
                } else if (Strfor_img2.contentEquals("noimag2")) {
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    options.inSampleSize = 5;
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
                        imgvw2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Strfor_img2 = "setimage2";
                    imgcross2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return;
                    //  Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(imgvw2);
                } else if (Strfor_img3.contentEquals("noimage3")) {
                    try {
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        options.inSampleSize = 5;
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
                            imgvw3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Strfor_img3 = "setimage3";
                        img_cross3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return;
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(imgvw3);
                } else if (Strfor_img4.contentEquals("noimage4")) {
                    try {
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        options.inSampleSize = 5;
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
                            imgvw4.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Strfor_img4 = "setimage4";
                        imgcross4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return;
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(pictureFile).into(imgvw4);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "your post is ready for upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };


    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "Turnstr");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("Turnstr", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    private static File getOutputMedia_video_File() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "Turnstr");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("Turnstr", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "video" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public class FileReader {

        public String getFileAsString(File file) {
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            DataInputStream dis = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                while (dis.available() != 0) {
                    sb.append(dis.readLine() + "\n");
                }
                fis.close();
                bis.close();
                dis.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (camera != null) {
            // java.lang.RuntimeException
            try {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
            } catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
        // camera = getCameraInstance();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();

        camera.unlock();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);

        //  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW));
        Video_path = getOutputMedia_video_File().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(Video_path);
        //Array_items.add(Video_path);
        recorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            //recorder.start();


        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            recorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            recorder = null;
            camera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    public static Bitmap getVidioThumbnail(String path) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                return bitmap;
            }
        }
        // MediaMetadataRetriever is available on API Level 8 but is hidden until API Level 10
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        Object instance = null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName("android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever");
            instance = clazz.newInstance();
            final Method method = clazz.getMethod("setDataSource", String.class);
            method.invoke(instance, path);
            // The method name changes between API Level 9 and 10.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                bitmap = (Bitmap) clazz.getMethod("captureFrame").invoke(instance);
            } else {
                final byte[] data = (byte[]) clazz.getMethod("getEmbeddedPicture").invoke(instance);
                if (data != null) {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                }
                if (bitmap == null) {
                    bitmap = (Bitmap) clazz.getMethod("getFrameAtTime").invoke(instance);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bitmap = null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (instance != null) {
                    clazz.getMethod("release").invoke(instance);
                }
            } catch (final Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
               // return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {

            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

//            try {
            bitmap.recycle();
//            }catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e){
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
            return bmRotated;

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, what is your question? Secondly please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Nirmal Any solution to avoid stretching camerA